# Attempting to check for first Firebase sign-in

Tags: java, android, firebase

My app uses Firebase's AuthUi to authenticate users. As I want them to have unique usernames, I am attempting to create a second activity that allows them to create a unique ID, but only if it is their first time logging in to the app. I am trying to check getCreationTimeStamp against getLastSignInTimestamp to achieve this. The following code send them to the username creation screen regardless of whether or not it is their first time signing in:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


if (requestCode == FB_AUTH_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


           FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = user.getMetadata();
            if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatListActivity.this, ChooseUsername.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                launchPlacePicker();
            }
```

Am I misunderstanding something about these metadata methods? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I guess the problem is getCreationtimestamp and lastSigninTimestamp will be the same no matter how many times you open or close the app. The lastSigningTimestamp will update until you logout and then login again.

Comment: Another idea is do not check if the user is login for the first time. Instead check if the user has already a username or not, If not open the activity to set it up.

Comment: Did my answer help you @aedgar777 , if it did, consider marking it as correct. I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this piece of code, to get confirmation about the app running for the first time on the device.

However, this would be done every time the user uninstalls and then reinstalls the app, to start.

```java
 boolean firstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
        if (firstRun){
            // do what you want to do for the first time user interacting with your app
            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).apply();
            }
```

And, if you want to have something permanent for the user. I'd suggest you to make a special node in your Firebase Database for this, in your user field.

And you can set it to be `true` only when the user makes a new ID, and then remove the node or set the value to `false` afterwards forever.